# Checkbox indeterminate for checkbox groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a groupbox of checkboxes, I want to link the groupbox with Themes checkbox[image: Groupbox checkbox]Themes image is an example.

How to link Theme1 and Theme2 with Themes?[image: Checkbox controlled by Example groupbox]

Comment: You mean checking both of them, when "Themes" has been checked?

Comment: ....but what happens when the **user** clicks "Themes" or "Checkbox"?  If they could select indeterminate state, how will your code know to check 1 or 2?  How is that easier than just clicking 1 or 2 as needed?

Comment: "Checkbox" checkbox sets checked/unchecked to Checkbox1 and Checkbox2, if Checkbox1.Checked = false and Checkbox2.Checked = true, "Checkbox" is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

You gave no indication what 'linking Themes to the groupbox' means nor what the indeterminate state means.  However, since checking/selecting `Theme1` probably excludes the use of `Theme2`, it seems like you are not using the right UI presentation (since the user **can** select both).

Consider a ComboBox with the Entries `{"No Theme", "Theme 1", "Theme 2"}`.  That way no one is confused and less form space is consumed.

Edit

If your edit really reflects what you want, set the "outside" check state whenever one of the inside checkbox's checkstate changes.  It still makes no sense - what do you do when the user checks/unchecks the outside box?

Comment: Or an option button (=radio button)?

Comment: Themes list checkbox is an example of groupbox checkbox, for example: Themes checkbox's checkstate changes with the groupbox.

Comment: If they check Theme1 **and** theme2 - which they can do, what do you use? it is still not clear why you need a third check to reflect the status of 2 other checks.  you probably want a set of radios, a combo or even the domainupdown control.  If `Themes` is meant to enable the groupbox and selection, it really is reflecting a "No Themes" selection.